# is RCT_EXPORT_VIEW_PROPERTY can be inherited

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I have several views . one is parent, the others are children.

parent has a field eg:
name

I have 
`RCT_EXPORT_VIEW_PROPERTY(name, NSString);` in parent.m, but it doesn't work.

I have to copy
`RCT_EXPORT_VIEW_PROPERTY(name, NSString);`
to all the children .

How to inherit RCT_EXPORT_VIEW_PROPERTY .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, properties cannot be inherited without source code modification of React-Native. React-Native looking only for methods implemented by concrete class without methods implemented by its superclasses.

You can define macro in superclass and use this macro inside subclasses:

```
#define EXPORT_COMMON_PROPERTIES \
RCT_EXPORT_VIEW_PROPERTY(propertyDefinedInParent, NSString) \
RCT_EXPORT_VIEW_PROPERTY(anotherPropertyDefinedInParent, NSString)
```

And then in .m file of children just use

```
EXPORT_COMMON_PROPERTIES;
```

UPDATE:
 We are actually not inheriting any properties from RCTViewManager. React-native exports all native props from ViewManagers as constants to js level. And then it just concatenate RCTViewManager's props with our component props:

```
 // The ViewConfig doesn't contain any props inherited from the view manager's
  // superclass, so we manually merge in the RCTView ones. Other inheritance
  // patterns are currenty not supported.
  const nativeProps = {
    ...UIManager.RCTView.NativeProps,
    ...viewConfig.NativeProps,
  };
```

- source code of [requireNativeComponent](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/b5421410ba4efbdf6e04face3b92c3f0143737b3/Libraries/ReactNative/requireNativeComponent.js) function.
But on native level we are not inheriting any properties from RCTViewManager.

Comment: It is a good way.

But we do inherit a lot of RCT_EXPORT_VIEW_PROPERTY from RCTViewManager. like 


     RCT_EXPORT_SHADOW_PROPERTY(width, float)
     RCT_EXPORT_SHADOW_PROPERTY(height, float)

How did react native made that?